# Counting QF-1 algebras inside quotient algebras of upper triangular matrices via Dyck paths

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

**Sorry, I modified the question. I first used the weaker version of QF-1. Now the problem is about weakly QF-1 and QF-1.** 
QF-1 rings are generalisations of Quasi-Frobenius rings. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Frobenius_ring#Thrall.27s_QF-1.2C2.2C3_generalizations.
The problem is as follows: Count the number of (weakly) QF-1 rings inside the class of (interesting) quotient algebras of the algebra of upper triangular matrices (we just look at admissible quotients here and those algebras are also called Nakayama algebras with a line as a quiver).

Algebraic background:

Let A always be an algebra of dominant dimension at least one (which our algebras always have).
Look at the following two properties:

1.A has dominant dimension at least two (which is equivalent to the condition that A has a double centralizer property with a minimal faithful projective-injective module)

2.Every module has dominant dimension or codominant dimension at least one.

Using a theorem of Morita for algebras with dominant dimension at least one (see the article "Frobenius algebras" by Yamagata corollary 3.5.1.), an algebra is QF-1 iff it has property 1. and 2. Call it weakly QF-1 if it has only property 2.

First some definitions: 
For a Dyck path look also at its interior: Namely the place between the Dyck path and the x-axis. Look at all the points, where a subDyck path of the original Dyck path passes trough.
The Dyck path corresponding to UUDUUDDUDD has as its points: (0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,2),(3,1),(4,0),(4,2),(5,1),(5,3),(6,0),(6,2),(7,1),(8,0),(8,2),(9,1),(10,0). 
Call a point inside a Dyck path good in case the diagonal to the right connecting the point and the boundary of the Dyck path ends to the right with a peak of the Dyck path OR the diagonal to the left connecting the point and the boundary of the Dyck path ends to the left with a peak of the Dyck path.
Call a Dyck path nice in case all its points are good.
The above example is not nice, since the point (5,1) is not good. 
An example of a nice Dyck path is UDUDUDUD.
Now the definition of dominant dimension, which is a little confusing (sorry).
Now define a projective point as a point on the top boundary connecting a point of height 0 to the left to the boundary (thus there are as many projective points as there are points of height 0 (which correspond to the simple modules of the algebra)).
Define the dimension of a point as the height+1 of the point.
Define $(a,b)=\Omega^{-1}(x,y)$ of a projective point (x,y) as the unique third point having dimension dim((c,d))-dim((x,y)) on the triangle with points (x,y),(c,d),(a,b), where (c,d) is the unique first peak right of the projective point.
Say the algebra has dominant dimension at least two iff for every projective point (x,y) , the point \Omega^{-1}(x,y) is on the top boundary and thus lying on a diagonal to the right to a peak.
Example: UUDUDUDD should have dominant dimension at least two, while UUDD has not.

If I made no mistake, the counting of weakly QF-1 algebras should reduce to the following:
Count the number of nice $2n-2$ -Dyck paths.
For n=2,3,... the numbers start as follows: 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 17, 37, 81, ... .

If I made no mistake, the counting of QF-1 algebras should reduce to the following:
Count the number of nice $2n-2$ -Dyck paths with dominant dimension at least two. The numbers start as 1,1,2,4,8,16,33,69,145,... (this looks like the sequence Martin Rubey obtained in the comments for the irreducible nice Dyck paths).
The examples with n=5 are UDUDUDUD and UUDUDUDD.
So questions:
Is there a nice description of nice Dyck paths and what is the formula to count them?

**edit:** Extended questions suggested by the work of Martin Rubey:
Find the generating function $F(q)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r}{a_k q^k}$ , when $a_k$ denotes the number of bad (=non-good points) in a Dyck path. Homological interpretation is: Bad points are exactly the indecomposable modules in the algebra with dominant and codominant dimension equal to zero.
(See the book by Auslander-Reiten-Smalo or https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~ringel/lectures/tachi/tachikawa/dominant.htm for motivation/definition of dominant dimension).

Comment: I think you forgot (1,1), right?

Comment: If the next value is $179$, which it seems to be, then the series is currently not in the OEIS.

Comment: Thank you for that. Still the sequence is so close to http://oeis.org/A132275 . A description would anyway be very interesting in my opinion since this might be the first classification of QF-1 rings inside a larger nontrivial class of algebras as far as I know. Sadly Im almost never able to solve my combinatorics problems after I found an elementary formulation.

Comment: I wanted to say http://oeis.org/A274114 instead of the above link

Comment: The number of Dyck paths without any good points appears to be $2^{r-1}$.

Comment: What do you mean? The points at the peak are always good (and more generally the points corresponding to the indecomposable projective or injective modules)

Comment: Sorry, I meant strictly below the path...

Comment: Ok, that also sounds interesting.

Comment: I added the number of bad points to http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000683.  However, is there maybe a more sensible statistic from which you can determine what you want?

Comment: IS there a way to show more generating functions ? Like till $F_{10}$ (for users not having sage on their current pc).

Comment: I found http://sagecell.sagemath.org/. What is the easiest/fastest way to get the generating function $F_n$ after using the code from http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000683? (Sorry never used sage)

Comment: If I made no mistake the first six generating functions are irreducible polynomials over Q.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000346 this is what i got for the first six generating function when adding the number of bad points in total.

Comment: In case it is of interest, the number of primitive good Dyck paths - that is, Dyck path that do not return to the axis except at the end, is $1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 33, 69, 145, 306, 649, 1382, 2951, 6314, 13532, 29042,\dots$

Comment: The total number of bad points for primitive Dyck paths of semilength $r$ is apparently $\sum_{i=0}^{r-2} \binom{2(r-2)}{i}$ which is http://oeis.org/A032443

Comment: Thats what i got for the differences in  [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 17, 37, 81, 179]: http://oeis.org/A024562

Comment: The number of good Dyck paths continues starts with $1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 17, 37, 81, 179, 399, 894, 2010, 4532, 10242\dots$

Comment: Again so close...

Comment: @MartinRubey for the number of nice Dyck paths with dominant dimension at least two I obtained 1,1,2,4,8,16,33,69,145, which seems to be the sequence you also got before in the comments for primitive nice Dyck paths.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following should work, but I'm off to bed now.

Let $G_k$ be the set of Dyck paths not containing a sub-path $U(UD)^\ell D$ where the first $U$ step begins at height $h\geq\ell-k$.  $G_1$ should be the set of good paths.  A path in $G_{k+1}$ is good even when prepending $k$ up and appending $k$ down steps, except for the paths $(UD)^\ell$ for $1\leq\ell\leq k$.

To get a recurrence, let $P_k$ be the set of paths in $G_k$ which do not return to the axis except at the end.

Then $P_k=\{U\, p\, D: p \in G_{k+1}\setminus \{UD,\dots,(UD)^k\}\}$ and $G_k$ is a (possibly empty) list of paths in $P_k$.

It remains to find out whether it is possible to extract $P_1$ from this.

Comment: Although this makes it very easy to compute very many terms - because $P_k=x+O(x^{k+2})$ - I do not see how to get a formula.  At least experimentally, it appears that the generating function for $P_1$ does not satisfy a polynomial differential equation of low order.

Comment: 0,1,0,1,1,2,4,8,16,33,69,145,306,649,1382,2951,6314,13532,29042,62400,134195,288805,621916,1339898,2887934,6226548,13428472,28967056,62497657,134862394,291054494,628209666,1356044528,2927357935,6319822205,13644466913,29459626725,63608295708,137345218455,296568100435,640390128805,1382842178159,2986119204672,6448328343838,13924889016050,30070468764658,64936950665315,140231732917445,302832855872802,653975682020594,1412283274900684,3049884440693621,6586369458499248,14223607096945155,30716675362520549,66334482060327825,143253434789279835,309365030786318198,668094350770584736,1442795284171769579,...

Comment: I got 1,1,2,4,8,16,33,69,145 (starting with n=3) for the number of nice Dyck paths with dominant dimension at least two, so maybe it is the same sequence with shifted beginning.

Comment: I saw your papers that you also work on module theoretic things. So the thing going from the point to the left diagonal just correpsonds to the projective cover and going to the right diagonal to the injective envelope. Peaks are just projetive-injective points. The dominant dimension at least two conditions looks not so nice/natural though.

Comment: I think there might be secret bijections between Dyck paths where the homological dimension have a better interpretation. For example the global dimension is in my interpretation (I associate the top boundary of the auslander-reiten quiver to the algebra) terrible complicated, but it is probaby just the height of the Dyck path in another interpretation. Same might be true for dominant dimension, namely it might have better interpretation using another bijection.

Comment: Please add the global dimension using your interpretation on Dyck paths to findstat: http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/NewStatistic.  Ideally, also supply code (in any language) to compute it.

Comment: I submitted it, but I do not use the Dyck path language in my programm so I had to to  10 examples by hand. I might write a code later which translates the [c_0,c_1,...,c_{n-1}] notation into Dyck path language. (I noted that I cannot submit without using Dyck path notation after writing everything else, so I still submitted) Is it somehow possible that I use the [c_0,c_1,...,c_{n-1}] for the values also? Then I could provide much more examples right now.

Comment: Added example in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/259113/global-dimension-and-dyck-path-combinatorics . Wanted to do something like that also in findstat but it might not be so easy since I did not use sage.

Comment: There is no need to use sage if you want to use findstat!