# generating function for Dyck paths avoiding a pattern

Tags: co.combinatorics

This is a follow up to [Counting QF-1 algebras inside quotient algebras of upper triangular matrices via Dyck paths](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259038). For $k\geq 1$ let $P_k=x+O(x^{k+2})$ be the formal power series that satisfies
$$
P_k = \frac{x}{1-P_{k+1}} - \frac{x^2(1-x^k)}{1-x}.
$$
I am interested in $P_1$, is there a nicer formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible expression. I have not tried to simplify it, maybe there actually is much simpler formula, I don't know.

$$
P_k(q)=1-(1-q)\frac{H(q^{k+2})}{H(q^{k+3})}
$$
with
$$
H(z)={}_1\phi_1\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\\left(\frac q{1-q}\right)^2\end{smallmatrix},q,\frac z{(1-q)^2}\right),
$$
where $_1\phi_1$ is the [basic hypergeometric function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/17.4); thus
\begin{align*}
H(z)&=1-\frac1{(1-q)((1-q)^2-q^2)}z\\
&+\frac q{(1-q)(1-q^2)((1-q)^2-q^2)((1-q)^2-q^3)}z^2\\
&-\frac{q^3}{(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)((1-q)^2-q^2)((1-q)^2-q^3)((1-q)^2-q^4)}z^3\\
&\cdots\\
&+(-1)^n\frac{q^{\binom n2}}{(1-q)\cdots(1-q^n)((1-q)^2-q^2)\cdots((1-q)^2-q^{n+1})}z^n\\
&\pm\cdots
\end{align*}

Here is a plot of the modulus for $P_1(q)$ inside the unit disc (color $=$ phase); I decided to add it because of a suggestive feature: strings of alternating poles and zeros along lines converging to $1$. It hints at a possible infinite product maybe somehow related to theta-functions.

[image]

At any rate the plot shows the pole nearest to the origin at $q=0.46305364318045766...$, so the leading asymptotics for coefficients must be of base reciprocal to this, i.e. $2.159577005228934...$. Indeed empirically the $n$th coefficient seems to be $\sim0.02700488448532407\times2.159577005228934^n$

What follows is not so much a proof, but rather sort of a heuristic explanation of how did I arrive at this; still I believe it is reasonably reliable.

From
$$
P_k(x)=-\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}x^2+\frac x{1-P_{k+1}(x)}
$$
we get
$$
P_k(x)=
-\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}x^2+\cfrac x{1+\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}x^2-\cfrac x{1+\frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}x^2-\cfrac x{1+\frac{1-x^{k+3}}{1-x}x^2-\cfrac x{\qquad\ddots}}}}.
$$

Let us introduce
$$
F_k(z,q)=-\frac{1-q^kz}{1-q}q^2+\cfrac q{1+\frac{1-q^{k+1}z}{1-q}q^2-\cfrac q{1+\frac{1-q^{k+2}z}{1-q}q^2-\cfrac q{1+\frac{1-q^{k+3}z}{1-q}q^2-\cfrac q{\qquad\ddots}}}},
$$
so that $P_k(q)=F_k(1,q)$. Then we get the functional equation
$$
F_k(z,q)=-\frac{1-q^kz}{1-q}q^2+\frac q{1-F_k(qz,q)}.
$$
To linearize this, let us introduce another function $A_k(z)$ given by
$$
\frac{1-q}{1-F_k(z,q)}=\frac{A_k(qz)}{A_k(z)},
$$
so that $P_k(q)=1-(1-q)\frac{A_k(1)}{A_k(q)}$.
The above functional equation then becomes
$$
(1-q)\frac{A_k(z)}{A_k(qz)}=1+\frac{1-q^kz}{1-q}q^2-\frac q{1-q}\frac{A_k(q^2z)}{A_k(qz)},
$$
so
$$
(1-q)^2A_k(z)=(1-q+(1-q^kz)q^2)A_k(qz)-qA_k(q^2z).
$$

If $A_k(z)=1+a_1z+a_2z^2+...$, then for the coefficients $a_n$ (with $a_0=1$) we get
$$
a_n=-\frac{q^{k+n+1}}{(1-q^n)((1-q)^2-q^{n+1})}a_{n-1}.
$$

This gives
$$
A_k(z)={}_1\phi_1\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\\left(\frac q{1-q}\right)^2\end{smallmatrix},q,\left(\frac q{1-q}\right)^2q^kz\right),
$$
or in our notation $A_k(z)=H(q^{k+2}z)$. Then the above equality $P_k(q)=1-(1-q)\frac{A_k(1)}{A_k(q)}$ gives the claimed expression.

PS And here is the Mathematica code that produced the plot, in case somebody would like to play with it

```
P1[q_]:=With[{c=(q/(1-q))^2},
 1-(1-q) QHypergeometricPFQ[{0},{c},q,q c]/QHypergeometricPFQ[{0},{c},q,q^2 c]]
ListPlot3D[Flatten[Table[
 With[{q=r E^(I a)},{r Cos[a],r Sin[a],Abs[P1[q]]}],
  {r,Table[1-1/n^2,{n,1.01,10,.01}]},{a,-\[Pi],\[Pi],\[Pi]/180}
 ],1],
 ColorFunction->(Hue[(\[Pi]+Arg[P1[#1+I #2]])/(2\[Pi])]&),
 ColorFunctionScaling->False, MeshFunctions->{(#3&)},Mesh->20]
```

Comment: Could you possibly contact me by email?

Comment: @MartinRubey Just did it :D